# Shinar is east of the Garden of Eden, two rivers run through it, 'Tigris' and 'Euphrates', do these rivers flow west to east and how far from Eden?

Tags: genesis

According to Gen. 11, men moved from the east to Shinar, a plain watered by two rivers, the Tigris and the Euphrates both mentioned in Gen. 2:10-14 as flowing from the Garden. what is the proximity of Shinar to the Garden of Eden? Do these rivers flow from west to east, or north to south?

Comment: Welcome to Biblical Hermeneutics! and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and [how it is different than others](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/653/how-can-we-educate-new-users-about-our-site-distinctives/803#803). I also recommend going through the [Help Center's](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/help) sections on both asking and answering questions.

Comment: We do not know anything much about the geography of Eden and the pre-flood earth as most of the earth was severely disrupted.

Answer (score 0):

The location of the Tigris and Euphrates is well known. Their course runs from the northwest to the southeast. Shinar basically means Babylonia. The map below, of course, is a modern reconstruction.

[image]

The [Jewish Encyclopida](https://jewishencyclopedia.com/articles/13582-shinar) provides the follow data about Shinar:

> Name for Babylonia occurring eight times in the Old Testament. In Gen.
> x. 10 the beginning of Nimrod's kingdom is said to have been "Babel,
> and Erech, and Accad, and Calneh, in the land of Shinar." In Gen. xi.
> 2, Shinar is the site of the tower of Babel; in Gen. xiv. 1, 9, the
> home of Amraphel, now generally identified with Hammurabi; in Dan. i.
> 1, the home of Nebuchadnezzar. The other passages in which the name is
> mentioned (Josh. vii. 21; Isa. xi. 11; Zech. v. 11) add no further
> information.

The exact location of Eden is a subject of almost endless discussion. However, based on the scriptures listed above, Shinar's location is not a mystery. Gen. 11:2 says the Tower of Babel was in Shinar. "Babel" was the ancient name of Babylon. Daniel 1:2 makes it clear that Shinar was the land ruled by Nebuchadnezzar, the king of Babylonia. As to the precise geography at literal existence of Eden, there are many opinions.